# Autohotkey regex "bug" involving CRLF

Tags: regex, newline

Here is an expression to delete any line in the clipboard that does not start with a letter "a":

```
Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "m)^[^a].+?`r`n", "")
```

Why does it delete the blank line *AND* the *"a fox"* line in the following list?

***a quick***
***a brown***

***a fox***
***a jumped***

My other regex application deletes the blank line only but not *"a fox"*. How would I write the expression to retain the *"a fox"* line?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this Pascal/Delpi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the blank line contains *no* characters, the pattern `^[^a]` matches and consumes the newline character, which is the next character after the start of line, and the rest if the pattern then matches up to the next newline consuming the next whole line.

In fact your pattern would remove *any* line after a blank line, whether it not it started with "a".

Try allowing either end-of-line or not an "a", like this:

```
Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "(?m)^($|[^a].+?)`r`n", "")
```